# Why does a self annotated trait is not assignable to the type of self?

Tags: scala, scala-3

```scala
trait Base

trait Plugin { base: Base =>
    def asBase: Base & Plugin = this
}

class Mix extends Base, Plugin

val plug: Plugin = new Mix
val baseA: Base= plug.asBase
val baseB: Base = plug // snorts with "Found: Plugin. Required: Base
```

Why?
If I am correct, the Liskov substitution principle is complied because all instances of `Plugin` are of a concrete type that is a mix that include a subtype of `Base`. Therefore, objects of type `Base`can be replaced with objects of type `Plugin` without affecting the correctness of the program.

Comment: **Scastie** reproducing the issue: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/D0ZAd9EIQ1KIUxn52IGl3Q/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Liskov principle says

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

> Subtype Requirement: Let `ϕ(x)` be a property provable about objects `x` of type `T`. Then `ϕ(y)` should be true for objects `y` of type `S` where `S` is a subtype of `T`.
>
> Preconditions cannot be strengthened in the subtype.
>
> Postconditions cannot be weakened in the subtype.
>
> Invariants must be preserved in the subtype.

Liskov principle is about subtyping. Liskov principle is now not applicable because `Plugin` is not a subtype of `Base`

```
implicitly[Plugin <:< Base] // doesn't compile
```

(`<:<` is weaker than `<:` https://stackoverflow.com/a/75762663/5249621 but this is ok for us; if `Plugin` were a subtype of `Base` i.e. `Plugin <: Base` then moreover `implicitly[Plugin <:< Base]` would be).

I guess you're confusing either `trait Plugin { base: Base => }` with `trait Plugin extends Base` or *subclasses* (inheritance) with *subtypes*

[What is the difference between a class and a type in Scala (and Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031640/what-is-the-difference-between-a-class-and-a-type-in-scala-and-java)

[What is the difference between Type and Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468145/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class)

https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html

[How to distinguish parameteric types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006684/how-to-distinguish-parameteric-types/)

[What is a difference between refinement type and anonymous subclass in Scala 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75149674/what-is-a-difference-between-refinement-type-and-anonymous-subclass-in-scala-3)

`trait Plugin extends Base` means that `Plugin` is a subclass of `Base`. In particular, this means that `Plugin` is a subtype of `Base`, so all subtypes of `Plugin` are subtypes of `Base`.
But `trait Plugin { base: Base => }` means that all *subclasses* of `Plugin` must be subclasses of `Base`. This doesn't mean that all *subtypes* of `Plugin` must be subtypes of `Base` (moreover, this doesn't mean that `Plugin` is a subtype of `Base`). Indeed, it's easy to declare a type

```
type SubPlugin <: Plugin
```

which is not a subtype of `Base`

```
implicitly[SubPlugin <:< Base] // doesn't compile
```

> all instances of `Plugin` are of a concrete type that is a mix that include a subtype of `Base`.

Even if it's true that all *values* (OOP instances) of `Plugin` are values (instances) of `Base` this doesn't make `Plugin` a subtype of `Base` and this doesn't mean that all *terms* of type `Plugin` are terms of type `Base`. For example the term `x` in `val x: Plugin = ???` is not a term of type `Base`.

You shouldn't think of a type as (only) a set of all values of the type (especially this becomes important in type-level programming where values are not so interesting at all).
Sets can be a model (in logical sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) for types. But sets and types are different

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/91330/what-exactly-is-the-semantic-difference-between-set-and-type

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489369/difference-between-a-type-and-a-set

https://planetmath.org/11typetheoryversussettheory

For example if we define two abstract types

```
type A

type B
```

then there are no values of these types. So these sets would be equal in set-theoretic sense (an empty set). But these types are different. In homotopy type theory (HoTT, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory) `1 = 2` and `1 = 3` are two types without any values but two different types.

> Therefore, objects of type `Base` can be replaced with objects of type `Plugin` without affecting the correctness of the program.

There are always programs that can't fail at runtime but that are rejected at compile time. For example `if true then 1 else "a"` can't fail at runtime but can be rejected by a language without subtyping e.g. Haskell (but not by Scala which thinks that this is `Any`). Scala rejects `val x: Int = if (true) 1 else "a"` although this can't fail at runtime either. Rich enough type system can't be sound and complete at the same time. Normally soundness is preferred over completeness

[What is a sound programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360792/what-is-a-sound-programming-language)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105575/what-is-the-difference-between-completeness-and-soundness-in-first-order-logic

You may ask why wouldn't always `trait Plugin { base: Base => }` mean the same as `trait Plugin extends Base`. Well, this was design decision of Scala type-system creators. In particular, if this would be the same then two different traits `trait A {this: B =>}`, `trait B {this: A =>}` would have the same type.

Also in `trait Plugin extends Base`, `Base` must be a class/trait. But in `trait Plugin { base: Base => }`, `Base` can be a type.

[Why scala self type is not a subtype of its requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968383/why-scala-self-type-is-not-a-subtype-of-its-requirement)

[What is the difference between self-types and trait subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses)

[Difference between trait inheritance and self type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224932/difference-between-trait-inheritance-and-self-type-annotation)

[What is more Scala idiomatic: trait TraitA extends TraitB or trait TraitA { self: TraitB => }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250374/what-is-more-scala-idiomatic-trait-traita-extends-traitb-or-trait-traita-self)

Comment: While I agree that the difference between class VS type is very important. I find this a limitation of the compiler TBH. Unless I am missing an example where you can get a `Plugin` that is also not a `Base`, then the compiler should be able to genera the synthetic subtyping relationship.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez What should the difference then be between `trait Plugin { base: Base => }`  and `trait Plugin extends Base`? Why should then you have `trait Plugin { base: Base => }` if you already have `trait Plugin extends Base`?

Comment: It depends on which context you put that question. If all you care are subtyping semantics then yes you are right. But, from a modelling / design perspective the idea of `self` types _(IMHO)_ is to let the but force the user to decide which specific implementation to mix-in. Normal subtyping does not necessarily provides that, at least not as nicely. For example, I usually make the mix-in `sealed` because I don't want users to be able to add new implementations, just pick one of the few I provide them.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ok, I see, with inheritance we specify a parent (`Base`) at the  definition site of `Plugin`, with self-type we have to additionally specify a parent (`Base`) at the definition site of `Plugin` inheritor . Probably you have to make `Base` sealed in both cases.

Comment: So, look at this example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/O3WnacSERJWqPWQEmfnA8Q/2 as you can see `b4` will not compile because it doesn't mix-in a plugin. Thre is no way _(AFAIK)_ to get that same behaviour without self-types.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Doesn't `b4` compile either in inheritance case because `b4` doesn't mix-in a plugin? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/OlQ6L1aIRROZm5WRfd1p7Q/1

Comment: BTW https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/7374

Comment: Sure, but you can override it yourself: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/B5Fs4D9aSwiKDtAygEuLuA And I don't want users to be able to do that, but pick one of my plugin implementations. _(for the record I have done this like 1 time in all my life, is not a common API design TBH)_

Comment: @DmytroMitin As we can see in the `asBase` method, the compiler knows that all instances of `Plugin` are assignable to `Plugin & Base`. So, would it be a good idea to add to the language the possibility of obtaining the type that every self annotated class's instance will have outside of the definition?
For example `Plugin.withSelfType` which would be of type `Plugin & Base`.
In this way, the relationship between `Plugin` and `Base` would not have to be repeated in various places in the code.